# ember-rails: Compiler said: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, handlebars.js

So I'm getting started with ember-rails and I'm having a an issue that's most vexing.

Ruby 2.1.0, Rails 4.0, Ember 1.10.0, Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta14.1, Ember-rails 0.16.1

I have consulted the documentation, google, and this [wonderful example app](https://github.com/justin808/ember-js-guides-railsonmaui-rails4) but I'm not having much luck. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what that might be.

Error:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-12 20:30:14 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by StuffController#index as HTML
  Rendered stuff/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 329ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Pre compilation failed for: {{render "navbar"}}
<div class="container-fluid">
    {{outlet}}
</div>

Compiler said: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window
  (in /Users/cboebel/Documents/Development/Ruby/VQ/app/assets/javascripts/templates/application.handlebars)):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>VQ</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8:   <%= favicon_link_tag '/assets/VQ-logo-transparent-RGB-72dpi.png' %>
    9: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___840981524341116597_2188195620'


  Rendered /Users/cboebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/cboebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (14.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/cboebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (24.7ms)
```

Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>VQ</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= favicon_link_tag '/assets/VQ-logo-transparent-RGB-72dpi.png' %>
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 60px;">
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html.erb is empty

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require best_in_place
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require_self
//= require app
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
    LOG_BINDINGS: true,
    LOG_RESOLVER: true,
    DEBUG: true
});
```

app.js

```
//= require store
//= require_tree ./adapters
//= require_tree ./mixins
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./controllers
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./helpers
//= require_tree ./components
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree ./routes
//= require router
//= require_self
```

application.handlebars

```
{{render "navbar"}}
<div class="container-fluid">
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

**Edit:**

I should point out that I have

```
config.ember.variant = :development
```

in development.rb

**Edit:**

I "fixed" this by doing a gem uninstall for the ember* gems and all the dependencies for ember-rails and then reinstalling them. Still not sure what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*short version for others*: **upgrade to ember-rails 0.16.2 (or greater) and downgrade handlebars from v3 to v2.**

re-installing upgraded you past [this checkin](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/commit/72a789e3facac84d173bdbfadfb9216ecc4e011f) ember-rails 0.16.1 was adding handlebars v3 which caused the 'cant find variable: window' issue.  ember-rails 0.16.2 has the fix for this problem.